# Parse Date from Script_Fields Params

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to find the elapsed time
**elapsed time**:  duration of time b/w `now` and `createdTime`

To pass the current_time (ie `now`) I have added it to the `params`, and I can access that in the `source` field  by writing `params['now']`
The problem is that this value of `params['now']` is a string and not of type date

The below example works as I have added `doc['updatedTime']`, in place of `params['now']`
how can I get it to work with `params['now']`

WORKING

```json
GET entity.incident_action_item/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "timeElapsed": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['updatedTime'].value.toInstant().getEpochSecond() - doc['createdTime'].value.toInstant().getEpochSecond()",
        "params": {
          "now": "2022-03-31T17:18:28.153+0530"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOT WORKING

```json
GET entity.incident_action_item/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "timeElapsed": {
      "script": {
        "source": "params['now'].value.toInstant().getEpochSecond() - doc['createdTime'].value.toInstant().getEpochSecond()",
        "params": {
          "now": "2022-03-31T17:18:28.153+0530"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple combinations and tried different methods supported by the painless language, I was not able to get it work

I faced one or the other exception

Answer (score 2):

## Tldr;

It is a format issue.

The `params[now]` holds a string type value. You need to convert the string into a `ZonedDateTime` or `DateTime`.

## String to ZonedDateTime

I have been using the `painless Lab` available in to run the following code.

```java
String datetime = "2022-03-31T17:18:28.153+0530";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxxx");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime, dtf);
return zdt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
      String dateTime = ctx._source.createDateTimeStr;
      
      
        DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, df);
          DateTimeFormatter df2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
  ctx._source.createDateTime = date.format(df2)

""",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do not need formater, just parse it.

```
"script_fields": {
    "test2": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
          "source": "ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(params.date); return zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of('Europe/London'));",
          "params": {
          "date": "2023-05-05T19:06:09.324Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```